Is there a SQL function that extract the alpha-ness/numeric-ness/whitespace-ness of characters in a string?
I'm using SQL Server 2014 and SSMS, and I have some data that's like  'abc123-123', I'd like to query whether all the entries look like this not.
Is there a way of creating this column "pattern":



id
Value
Pattern




1
jam\21
aaax11


2
byt9*9
aaa1x1


3
21y 21
11ax11



So that I can do a count grouped by pattern?
As long as it can differentiate alpha characters from numeric characters and those two from anything else, I can probably make it work!
Basically looking for something along the lines of:
SELECT PATTERN, COUNT(*)
FROM 
    (SELECT id, value, GETPATTERN(value) AS PATTERN
     FROM have) AS A
GROUP BY PATTERN
ORDER BY 2 DESC

With some help around this GETPATTERN function, assuming such a thing exists.
In Python it's basically trivial:
def getalphanumberwhite(inString):
    resultList = []
    resultstring = ""
    for i in inString:
        if i.isnumeric():
            resultList.append("1")
        elif i.isalpha():
           resultList.append("a")
        else:
            resultList.append("x")    
    resultstring=''.join(resultList)
    return resultstring

print(getalphanumberwhite("Jam21&I 32"))
#Returns aaa11xax11

Thanks

You could implement this using a series of regex replacements, but SQL Server has basically no regex support out of the box.

Your custom GETPATTERN function might use something like this: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/217039/replace-all-numeric-values-with-single-character

This might help  https://forums.sqlteam.com/t/extract-pattern-from-a-string/6444

On later versions you could use TRANSLATE. For SQL Server 2014 you could do 25 nested REPLACE to convert all characters from B-Z to A and a further 9 to replace all digits except 1 with 1 etc.

Such UDF is simple to create...
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.F_COMPUTE_PATTERN (@STRING NVARCHAR(4000))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(4000)
WITH RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
AS
BEGIN
   IF @STRING = N''
      RETURN N'';
   DECLARE @I SMALLINT = 1, @C NCHAR(1), @RETURN NVARCHAR(4000) = N'';
   WHILE @I <= LEN(@STRING)
   BEGIN
      SET @C = SUBSTRING(@STRING, @I, 1);
      SET @RETURN = @RETURN
                  + CASE 
                       WHEN @C BETWEEN '0' AND '9' THEN '1'                       
                       WHEN @C BETWEEN 'a' AND 'z' THEN 'a'
                       ELSE '-'
                    END;
      SET @I = @I + 1;
   END;
   RETURN @RETURN
END;
GO

And now you can do :
WITH
T AS (SELECT * 
      FROM (VALUES (1, 'jam\21'), 
                   (2, 'byt9*9'), 
                   (3, '21y 21')) A (id, val)
      )
SELECT *, dbo.F_COMPUTE_PATTERN(val) AS PATTERN
FROM   T;

That's the results :
id   val     PATTERN
---- ------- ---------
1    jam\21  aaa-11
2    byt9*9  aaa1-1
3    21y 21  11a-11

But beware of collations...

I must say that @user25043454 gives more complex functions, but the fact that those functions are inline table valued functions make them a little bit faster on wide datasets
